# Checking if element is visible on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this github source code here https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible
I am trying to check if the div labeled "test" is visible to the viewport and add a class to an element.

I've tried this here.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        var detectPartial = $('#test').val() == 'partial';

        // Is this element visible onscreen?
        var visible = $(this).visible( detectPartial );

        // Set the visible status into the span.

        if(visible) {
            $('#test').addClass('active');
        }
    });
```

Script Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($('#test').visible()){
            $('.contact').addClass('active');
            $('.home').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $('.home').addClass('active');
            $('.contact').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="test" id="test" style="height: 700px"></div>

<li class="main-li"><a href="#" class="nav-links contact" id="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
```

I am trying to check if `test` is visible to the viewport.
If it is visible then add `active` class to `contact`.

Comment: What is your question? Is it not working?

Comment: It is not working.
It does not do anything.

Comment: What is this meant to do? `var detectPartial = $('#test').val() == 'partial';`  I don't think you can use `.val()` on `div` elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to achieve that result.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('#test').visible()) {
        $('#test').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the `.val()` method, and your `$(this)` won't have any relation to the `#test` div the way things are. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: I was reading the github code incorrectly. I appreciate this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Trying out this code. It seemed to work at first... It immediately adds the class to contact on any scroll motion.
I edited my post with new code.